# Forum Software Compatible with Facebook [and Wordpress] Integration

Tags: web-applications, forum

Which forum software is the most usable and compatible with Facebook and Wordpress integration?

By usable, I mean that is easy to use for end-users, and also easy to make modifications/plugins for coders. The forum's speed is also a consideration. And by Facebook and Wordpress integration, I mean us something like Facebook Connect in which users can register using their Facebook account.

I'm thinking of vBulletin (vB), Invision Power Board (IPB), and Simple Machines Forum (SMF); but still not sure which one to use. If there's any more suggestion, I'll be glad to know, though I'm not considering bbPress since I need something bigger than that..

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Discuz is another option you can look into (though its English version stopped development)

Comment: Discuz doesn't seem like a complete forum I suppose... I'm looking for something more big like Invision or vBulletin--flat forums boards. Where people could edit profile, shows their total posts, and the likes..

Comment: Discuz is the world's most comprehensive forum. A lot of world-class forums are using the software.  You must overlook its feature list. Tons of plugins available as well. Better than a lot paid forum software like vBulletin.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that users actually want FB Connect?  I have found that users prefer to keep their FB persona COMPLETELY separate from their forum persona.  On forums I run, FB Connect was either ignored by users, generated complaints (imported wrong email or inappropriate avatar), or failed to connect when a  user tried to log in.  My experience suggests that you should not waste effort on FB connect.  Instead I would focus on making the traditional registration easier for new users to sign up.  My $0.02.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: does discuz have a private messaging system, profile customization, and anything else that forum software have? I have looked at many examples but I can't find nothing like they have on vBulletion.com or Xenforo.com or any other appropriate forum softwares. Because the forum I have to create requires more than discussions.

Comment: @mikey_w I'm sure. In fact, my members demand it themselves (I'm upgrading from older Invision). I think it's pretty different experience with folks in USA. In Indonesia, almost everyone wants their stuff connected with Facebook.

Comment: @deathlock Yes. Discuz has PM system, profile customization & all sorts of forum features like mini games, bank, blog, photo album, Twitter-like message, etc. For more information, look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discuz! is a sophisticated PHP+MySQL-based forum software made by a Chinese company. Though it is "Made in China", it has all-round features for all uses as it provides all sorts of plugins and extension.

However, one disadvantage for Discuz! is that the developer stops developing English version. Luckily, there are still many English-speaking developers willing to continue translating Discuz! to English version. Here is an Indonesian site (mainly in English): http://discuzindo.net/ , which you can download the software in English version.

Comment: Whoa, so I had been thinking different software (I thought you were referring to Disqus). Have seen this software several times but never had known the name. It's not really well-known, is it? Since I'm targeting my forum to survive in 3-4 years, is the community active enough to provide supports?

Comment: Discuz is the largest forum software in terms of user base in the world and the developer is a holding company. No worry. It will be okay.

Comment: Okay, thanks... since I'm considering several options, do you have other suggestion? And perhaps a comparison to Discuz if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Discuz X2.5 is more than you can imagine, it is powerful than you think and much more complex and flexible over VBB,IPB,PHPBB,Xenforo, but the reason I do not recommend you to set up a forum using Discuz is because the language it employed is Chinese,you have to put lots of efforts to turn it to English, it is possible but not without a team, i18n has words counts bigger than a novel, many Chinese words are scattered across files including .php/htm and the likes.

Answer (score -1):

yeah im using now Discuz because this company here in China its using

> discuz

so i have installed all(php apache...) and have a a experience here is Ok!. but when u really want to develop a good app its not nice, just giving me many problems,  `thinkphp` its easy and very comfortable when i used that, i have used in the class because the teacher want to use it. 
anyway i have many problems. i also dont recommend even if u can read Chinese haah maybe if they modify